# Menu icons like in "Ice cream Sandwich"

Tags: android

Not really sure if it's appropriate to ask on stackoverflow, but. I'm writing app for android 4.0 and in desperate need of different menu and action bar icons in the new style ( I think such icons were also in honeycomb).
Does anyone know any android style icons resources?

Answer (score 1):

Use Holo.Light theme in the application tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some digging up in the resources of the SDK?

Most of the icons can be found in there !

You can find it in your sdk/platform/`<version>`/data/res/

Comment: Yep. I got all what I need from SDK, but I need any other icons with the same style to use in the app. Not necessary from google, but in the same minimalistic style.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, I think this is what you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack

It takes some extra work to create your own icons but having a template pack, you are unrestricted to using only what others may have done. I have searched the Internet many times for nice and appropriate icons for my application and came to the conclusion that it's best to go with one's own freedom.